# Problemas com a connectionString no ASP.NET C# CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

sou novo no ASP.NET com C# e estou com um problema para acessar as informações no meu web.config.

Essa é a tag de conexão com a base de dados:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="someConnection" connectionString="SomeInformation" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`
```

Essa é a função que estou usando para tentar recuperar as informações:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Isso me retorna o erro "Usar o genérico do tipo ConfigutationManager requer 1 argumento de tipo", mas já tentei tipar o configurationManager e sempre retorna o erro "ConfigurationManager não contém uma definição para ConnectionStrings", independente do "**T**" que eu coloque.

Preciso de ajuda, obrigado.

Comment: Olá, asp.net-core e `web.config`? você não deveria estar colocando as suas configurações no `appsettings.json`? Dê uma olhada na documentação e tutorial https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Poderia adicionar o arquivo *.csproj do seu projeto, para que seja confirmada a versão do .net que é usada?

Comment: Desculpa, peguei a conexão do projeto errado, o correto é esse, do arquivo json:

"ConnectionString": "Host= localhost; user= user; pass=pass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comando correto usando a lib System.Configuration 4.0.0 é

> ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[paramName];

Answer (score 0):

Conforme [essa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0), você precisa adicionar o pacote nuget `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` ao seu projeto.

Depois disso, você acessa o `ConfigurationManager` através da namespace `System.Configuration`.

Exemplo:

```
var conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

O ASP.NET core tem uma função melhor para buscar connection strings.  Sugiro usar o: `Configuration.GetConnectionString("{NomeDaSuaConnectionString}")`

Tem mais informações sobre como conectar suas aplicações ASP.NET core na propria documentação da microsoft nesse link: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)